# Почему в списке не целые числа?

Tags: python-3.x, списки

```
bulletX, bulletY = 450, 450
strela = Sprite(bulletX, bulletY, 'Assets/Images/strela.png')
bullets.append(strela)
bulletsX.append(bulletX)
bulletsY.append(bulletY)
```

Дальше начинаю работать с элементами списка:

```
vel_x, vel_y = mouseX - bulletsX[i], mouseY - bulletsY[i]
```

выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Sprite
```

Comment: как у вас объявлен bullets?

Comment: bullets = [ ] вот так

Comment: а `i`  у вас это что? Ошибка говорит о том, что вы используете `Sprite` как индекс списка

Comment: но ведь в список (bulletsX, bulletsY) добавлены целые числа

Comment: ну покажите как вы `i` задали, сами bulletsX верно задаются и если обратиться через bulletsX[0], то сработает. Однако ошибка говорит что `i` это объект `Sprite`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: аааааааааа до меня дошло. надо не for i in bullets? а for i in bulletsX и bulletsY, туплю однако, спасибо